# Animate hr tags entry and exit on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to animate hr tag in an anchor tag. Basically what I want is on hover over the anchor tag the hr tag should slide out to the right and on moving out the mouse, the hr tag should slide in from the left.

What I have done till now is on hover the hr tag slides out to the left instead to the right and on moving out the mouse it slides back in from the left.

I want to achieve something like the following:
[image]

**Button Component**

```
<Fragment>
    <Link className="btn" to={ this.props.linkTo }>
        <div>
            <span>{ this.props.text }</span>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </Link>
</Fragment>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    color: var(--black);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
}
.btn > div > span {
    line-height: 30px;
}
.btn > div > hr {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid var(--black);
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-out;
}
.btn:hover div > hr {
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a sandbox so I can play with?

Comment: @Brian Le, I would be happy to do it but currently am on a mobile device.

Comment: Lemme do it then. It's that all the code you currently have?

Comment: Yes, It's just the react component am working on.

Comment: You know what, you alright got a really nice and simple answer down there. Check it out

Comment: @Brian Le checked. But it leaves a small dot to the right when hover animation completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use float property for this. Here is a simple example with plain HTML.

```css
div > hr {
  transition: width 1s ease-out; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 1s  ease-out;
  width : 100%;
  float: left;
}
div:hover > hr {
   width:0%;
   float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>
  Fooo Barrr
  </h2>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and simple!

Comment: Nice. :) Almost the way I am looking for but it leaves a small dot to the right when hover animation is completed. Can it be done without float as every other part of the layout is being done with flexbox?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `float` property along with the `border-style` and `height` of `hr`. You can also change the `background-color` of the `hr`.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.container{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.container > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:20px;
}
.container > hr {
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  border-style: none;
  background: #000;
  height: 2px;
  margin:0;
}
.container:hover > hr {
  width:0%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>See what we do</span>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float right will get it to transition to the right, and when it comes back, it'll also be from left to right, much like the image you posted.

> .btn:hover div > hr {   width: 0;   float: right; }